# Only a hobby/to refer to painting

Tags: word-choice

If I want to say that I like painting,  but I am not a professional artist can I use the sentence below?

> I am not an artist. It's only my hobby.

Comment: Yes, you can say that, or 'I just like to paint in my spare time'.

Comment: Similar to what Kate said, _I like painting in my free/spare time._ or _I am not a pro, it's just my hobby._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say that, or 'I just like to paint in my spare time'. – Kate Bunting

This is more modest than saying *I'm not a professional*. Saying, *I'm not a professional* provides petty individuals an opportunity to tell others that you believe your painting is good enough to be mistaken as having been made by a professional painter. Consider your audience when saying, *I am not a pro*. -- EllieK

Comment: This is more modest than saying *I'm not a professional.*  Saying, *I'm not a professional* provides petty individuals an opportunity to tell others that you believe your painting is good enough to be mistaken as having been made by a professional painter.  Consider your audience when saying, *I am not a pro.*